# Applying multiple CQL_FILTER to single GeoServer LayerGroup?

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers

I've created a page with OpenLayers 3 that adds a WMS Tile layer to the map served up by a local GeoServer (v2.6) instance.  As it stands adding layer by layer things work just fine:

```
var dynamicMap = new ol.Map({
  target: 'myMap',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
        params: {
          'LAYERS': 'ne:NE1_HR_LC_SR_W_DR'
        }
      })
    }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
        url: 'http://localgeoserver:8080/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'CQL_FILTER':"[(USAGE IN ('H','B')]", 'TILED': true, 'layers':'WORKSPACENAME:LAYER1','WIDTH':'256','HEIGHT':'256' },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      }))
    }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
        url: 'http://localgeoserver:8080/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'CQL_FILTER':"[SYMBOL IN ('A','B','C')]", 'TILED': true, 'layers':'WORKSPACENAME:LAYER2','WIDTH':'256','HEIGHT':'256' },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      }))
    })
  ]
});
```

I plan to add several more layers to GeoServer, and rather than making WMS requests for each layer, I want to put them all in a Layergroup in GeoServer.  I did that --

```
new ol.layer.Tile({      
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
    url: 'http://localgeoserver:8080/geoserver/wms',
    params: {'TILED': true, 'layers':'WORKSPACENAME:LAYERGROUP1','WIDTH':'256','HEIGHT':'256' },
    serverType: 'geoserver'
  }))
})
```

and again all the layers return as I expect them to, with one exception - I'm not sure how to apply the necessary CQL_FILTER to my layergroup.  When I added the first CQL_FILTER `[(USAGE IN ('H','B')]` when adding the LAYERGROUP1 layergroup as a layer, it failed because USAGE was not found in the LAYER2 layer.

I tried examples I saw where people said that each CQL_FILTER needs to be delimited by a semicolon, but that didn't seem to work either.

Is my end goal even possible going this route?

Is there a way to apply CQL_FILTERS when creating my layers in GeoServer?

Each layer is simply referencing an Oracle table, so should I go so far as to just create each layer with SQL and just apply my filters in the WHERE clause there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that layergroup behaves like a one layer and therefore you can't use two CQL_FILTERs which are separated with semicolon as if you were asking two layers.

What you can do is to ask two layers with one request and give different CQL_FILTERS for those two as a list. This request is selecting New York from topp:states and point named "fire" from tiger_poi:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=346&LAYERS=topp:states,tiger:poi&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=-74.01531543884973,40.7072072479969,-73.99804660283719,40.720224714795016&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME='New York';NAME='fire'
```

Two layers without CQL-filters

[image: without filters]

Two layer with CQL-filters

[image: with filters]

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here, mine was including `INCLUDE` in the query like:

> CQL_FILTER=INCLUDE;STATE_NAME='New York' AND NAME='fire'

Ref:http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#filter-ecql-reference

looks much easier!

Comment: Worked for 2 different columns/attribute of same layer ```http://localhost:8585/geoserver/aasdagrometgis/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=aasdagrometgis:railway_shapefile&CQL_FILTER=FROM='DELHI' AND TO='ROHTAK'&outputFormat=application/json```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that using a semi-colon between multiple filters does not work anymore.  At least for geoserver versions `2.10.0+` and `2.11.0`.

Using the above example this is what we required:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=346&LAYERS=topp:states,tiger:poi&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=-74.01531543884973,40.7072072479969,-73.99804660283719,40.720224714795016&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME='New York' AND NAME='fire'
```

Specifically in our case, a property filter & BBOX constraint was needed. Something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=346&LAYERS=topp:states,tiger:poi&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=-74.01531543884973,40.7072072479969,-73.99804660283719,40.720224714795016&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME='New York' AND BBOX(the_geom,151.189689956364,-33.843758285941,151.222261898414,-33.833341634382)
```

Comment: Worked in GeoServer 2.13.0 as explained in the above answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/118158/52577 by @user30184.