# Adding multiple layers in GeoServer WMS URL

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms

I have a URL that I am passing into an API call to bring back a static image of a map. This URL currently works:

```
http://computername:8080/geoserver/Packt/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Packt:countries&styles=&bbox=-181.800003051758,-90.8669281005859,181.800003051758,84.4676055908203&width=768&height=370&srs=EPSG:4326&CQL_FILTER=continent%20%3D%20%27North+America%27&format=application/openlayers#
```

In the book I am reading it says the layers parameter can 'insert a comma-separated list of layers' but when I try to add another layer like so:

```
http://computername:8080/geoserver/Packt/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Packt:countries,Packt:ne_10m_railroads&styles=&bbox=-181.800003051758,-90.8669281005859,181.800003051758,84.4676055908203&width=768&height=370&srs=EPSG:4326&CQL_FILTER=continent%20%3D%20%27North+America%27&format=application/openlayers#
```

the browser does not accept it. My end goal is to call two layers and filter one of the layers with the CQL syntax.

I am running GeoServer 2.11.0 on Apache Tomcat 8.5 on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer and example at [Applying multiple CQL_FILTER to single GeoServer LayerGroup?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118152/applying-multiple-cql-filter-to-single-geoserver-layergroup/118158#118158).

It seems that if you use CQL_FILTER with a list of layers you must also define some filter for each layer. Thus this does not work

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=346&LAYERS=topp:states,tiger:poi&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image/png&BBOX=-74.01531543884973,40.7072072479969,-73.99804660283719,40.720224714795016&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME='New York'
```

Adding an empty second filter `CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME='New York';` 
does not seem to work. However, if you add a bogus second filter `CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME='New York';1=2` then the request does work

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=346&LAYERS=topp:states,tiger:poi&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image/png&BBOX=-74.01531543884973,40.7072072479969,-73.99804660283719,40.720224714795016&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME='New York';1=2
```

Comment: There are 2 "bonus" filters INCLUDE & EXCLUDE you can use instead of 1=2

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you need to specify, which layer the cql filter belongs to:

See http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#cql-filter

> If more than one layer is specified in the layers parameter, then a
>   separate filter can be specified for each layer, separated by
>   semicolons. The syntax is:

`cql_filter=filter1;filter2...`

So your request would become:

```
http://computername:8080/geoserver/Packt/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Packt:countries,Packt:ne_10m_railroads&styles=&bbox=-181.800003051758,-90.8669281005859,181.800003051758,84.4676055908203&width=768&height=370&srs=EPSG:4326&CQL_FILTER=continent%20%3D%20%27North+America%27;&format=application/openlayers#
```

I haven't tested it though.